# Setting Teradata SQL Assistant as default SQL engine

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have both SQL Server (SSMS) and Teradata SQL Assistant installed on my machine. I primarily work in the Teradata application and wish to use Teradata as my default application for opening SQL files but currently all sql files saved to my machine are automatically saving as Microsoft SQL Server file types and opening in SSMS. I try to use the "Open with" option to select Teradata but Teradata does not appear in the list. Does anyone know how I can set Teradata to be my default sql app to open .sql files?

Comment: Try *More Apps* first and if it doesn't show SQL Qssistant click on *Look for another App on this PC*...

Comment: @dnoeth I tried the "More apps" option and Teradata was not listed. Then I tried the "look for another app on this PC" but it took me to the file directory but I'm not sure what option to select from there because Teradata was listed as a file folder but not selectable. It seems like maybe there is something that should be selected within the Teradata folder but I'm not sure which option.

Comment: Choose `SQLA.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Teradata\Client\16.20\Bin`